# left_chat_member not invoked

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

***Bot Description***

I'm using [TelegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/) for develop a `Telegram` bot.
I've created my own middleware that should handle all the update messages sended to a group, in particular, if the update is a service message the bot must remove it.

***The Problem***

The problem's that the bot only catch `new_chat_members` but when a user left the chat, the event `left_chat_member` is not invoked.

*Middleware code*

```
class MessageHandler {
    /**
     * Check if is a message service
     */
    _checkServiceMessage(ctx) {
        let unwantedMessages = ['new_chat_members', 'left_chat_member', 'new_chat_title'];
        let isUnwanted = unwantedMessages.some(x => ctx.updateSubTypes.includes(x));

        if (isUnwanted) {

            console.log(ctx.updateSubTypes);

            // Delete service message
            ctx.deleteMessage().then(function (result) {

                // add or remove user to my own db

            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    }

    middleware() {
        return (ctx, next) => {

            this._checkServiceMessage(ctx);

            return next();
        }
    }
}

module.exports = MessageHandler;
```

this is how to use the `Middleware`:

```
const Telegraf = require('telegraf');
const MessageHandler = require('../middlewares/handler');
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);
bot.use(new MessageHandler().middleware());
bot.startPolling();
```

***How to replicate***

1. Create a Telegram bot using [@BothFather](https://telegram.me/BotFather)
2. Replace the token got from `BothFather` in `process.env.BOT_TOKEN`
3. Create the bot pasting the code above
4. Create a group and with another account join to the group
5. In the console will appear `new_chat_members`
6. Now lef the group, as you can see the event `left_chat_member` will not appear.

The weird thing is that: if I remove ctx.deleteMessage(), so all the codes in `isUnwanted`, the event `left_chat_member` appear.

I threw away days on this problem and I can't get over it. I opened a ticket on TelegrafJS but so far nothing yet.

I need to store in my own database the user which join to my group, and remove when a user leave.

In my code I used the bot in two groups, I don't know if this could cause a problem but I don't think so.

Could someone explain me what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Bots with privacy mode enabled don't get service message updates ([as well as other types of updates](https://core.telegram.org/bots/#privacy-mode)). Telegram also doesn't send leave events if the group has >50 members.

Comment: Privacy mode is disabled and also the group doesn't have more of 6 members, so I don't think the problem is linked to what you said

Comment: Is it a new group? I believe new groups don't get certain service messages for a bit.

Comment: Yes is a new group. I don't know for the service message, I can't find anything related on the doc